# Alamofire request cancelled (-999)

Tags: swift, upload, request, alamofire

I want to make use of the RequestAdapter and RequestRetrier protocols, so I created my own so called AuthenticationHandler class which implements both protocols. I do this because the refresh token may be expired so this mechanism comes in handy.
The RequestAdapter protocol method **adapt** does get called, but the **should** RequestRetrier protocol method does not. I have a separate class that does the actual request:

```
class TestRequest {

var authHandler: AuthenticationHandler?

func executeRequest() {
    // For testing purposes a false access token is passed
    self.authHandler = AuthenticationHandler(accessToken: "some_default_token")

    let sessionManager = SessionManager()
    sessionManager.adapter = authHandler
    sessionManager.retrier = authHandler

    var loginModel : LoginMessage = LoginMessage.init()

    loginModel.username = "someUserName"
    loginModel.password = "WrongPassword"

    do {
        let binaryData = try loginModel.serializedData()

        // Create a file with this binary data in order to use it as part of the multipart formdata
        guard let fileURL = createFileFrom(data: binaryData) else {
            print("Error creating file")
            return
        }

        // Note: custom headers have been set in the AuthenticationHandler

        sessionManager.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(fileURL, withName: "content")
        },
                              to: K.endpointLogin) { (encodingResult) in
                                switch encodingResult{
                                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                                        print("Encoding result success...")
                                        print("Statuscode: \(response.response?.statusCode)")
                                        print(response)
                                    }
                                case .failure(let encodingError):
                                    print("Failure: \(encodingError)")
                                }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }       
}
```

I have followed the example in the documentation [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#adapting-and-retrying-requests)

I have read several previous posts saying it has to do with retaining the sessionManager. But I think that is also covered. My authentication handler looks like this:

```
class AuthenticationHandler: RequestAdapter, RequestRetrier {

private typealias RefreshCompletion = (_ succeeded: Bool, _ accessToken: String?) -> Void

private let sessionManager: SessionManager = {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
    return SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
}()

private let lock = NSLock()

private var accessToken: String

private var isRefreshing = false
private var requestsToRetry: [RequestRetryCompletion] = []

init(accessToken: String) {
    self.accessToken = accessToken
}

// MARK: - RequestAdapter protocol method

func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) throws -> URLRequest {
    var urlRequest = urlRequest

    if let urlString = urlRequest.url?.absoluteString, urlString.hasPrefix(K.SERVER_URL) {
        urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        urlRequest.setValue("multipart/form-data", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        urlRequest.setValue("Bearer " + accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    }

    return urlRequest
}

// MARK: - RequestRetrier protocol method

func should(_ manager: SessionManager, retry request: Request, with error: Error, completion: @escaping RequestRetryCompletion) {
    lock.lock() ; defer { lock.unlock() }
    }
}
```

My config is as follows:

- Alamofire version: 4.7.2
- Xcode version: 9.4.1
- Swift version: 4

What am I doing wrong here? Why is the request cancelled and is the **should** method not called?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your core issue is that your `SessionManager` instance is being `deinit`ed, which cancels any ongoing tasks. You should keep it around in a singleton or something similar, which will fix the other issue, that of using a new `SessionManager` for each request, which is an anti pattern.

Comment: This solved the problem; creating a separate class which holds a static `SessionManager` and use this in the TestRequest class. The sessionManager instance in the AuthenticationHandler can then be removed.

Comment: However the should method still does not get called. The encodingResult has a value of success, but the response had a statuscode of 401. What am I missing here?

Comment: Oh wow, chaining the validate method does trigger the callback. So in case of a successful encodingResult I need to do this:
`case .success(let upload, _, _): upload.validate().responseJSON {response in ... do something with the response...`